# how to pass a value using thymeleaf to data of bootstrap?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, bootstrap-grid

I want to use Thymeleaf to pass a value to data from Bootstrap.

I don't know how to do it.  Can you help me?

```
<tr th:each="car : ${lCars}" class="succes">
  <td th:text="${car.id}"></td>
  <td th:text="${car.name}"></td>
  <td align="center">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar" title="Edit"
      data-id= "th:text="${car.id}""    <!-- I want to pass this value on to the data, but this way doesn't work -->
      data-name="myCar" <!-- If I send a simple word, works well -->

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line makes no sense:
    data-id="th:text="${car.id}""

1. The purpose of th:text is to modify the body text of the element (in this case, a button element). You're trying to set an attribute value.
2. If you want thymeleaf to modify a data attribute like data-id, you need to th:attr instead

That line should be written as follows:

```
data-id="" th:attr="data-id=${car.id}"
```

If you want the data-id to have some default value like "example-id", do this:

```
data-id="example-id" th:attr="data-id=${car.id}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What i should i do if i want to add another attribute to the same button?
data-id="" th:attr="data-id=${car.id}" 

example:
data-name="" th:attr="data-name=${car.name}" 

Because it works well with one attribute, but when i add other data i have problems, because the first attribute was assigned to the button

i hope you can help me

Comment: To solve this i used:  th:attr="data-id=${car.id},data-name=${car.name}"

Comment: Reiko, you are the boss giving me the idea to list them with comma! thanks